# get JSON API data by user login

Tags: android, json, api

I have a JSON API for show transaction history, but I want to show it by user who log in and do transaction, below is my API response :

```js
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "trxid": "12970",
      "tagihan_id": null,
      "code": "I5",
      "produk": "INDOSAT 5000",
      "harga": "5895",
      "target": "085800000864",
      "mtrpln": "-",
      "note": "Trx I5 085800000864 Sukses. SN : 526549528059",
      "token": "526549528059",
      "status": "1",
      "saldo_before_trx": "117160",
      "saldo_after_trx": "111265",
      "created_at": "2018-05-17 09:29:47",
      "updated_at": "2018-05-17 09:34:02"
    },
    {
      "trxid": "20839",
      "tagihan_id": null,
      "code": "I5",
      "produk": "INDOSAT 5000",
      "harga": "5895",
      "target": "081226442307",
      "mtrpln": "-",
      "note": "Gagal Nomor tujuan salah mohon cek kembali nomornya. Saldo dikembalikan",
      "token": "-",
      "status": "2",
      "saldo_before_trx": "516305",
      "saldo_after_trx": "516305",
      "created_at": "2018-07-06 05:37:26",
      "updated_at": "2018-07-06 05:38:03"
    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Are you trying the API's response to only show the value's of the user logged in? In that case, do you know the users id or so?

Comment: yes, i want the API's response and only show the value's of the one user transaction do, not all of the users do, and i know the users id

Comment: So, the real question is how to filter a JSON array based on a key's value? What language are you using?

Comment: iam using java on android studio

Comment: and volley to parse data from api